# Oops! Something Bad Happened

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, user-interface

Well, for more information:

I was at the Area51 users site, editing my profile name. Hit the TAB key, then moused down to the `Save` button, and clicked.

Then I got the really cool and thoughtful exception dialog explaining that I wasn't the one to fault and that you guys are aware of the error and will be diligently working at fixing the issue. So I thought I would return the gesture and give as much information as I could at the time of the exception. I wish all customers/users of my software were so diligent *and thoughtful* in their error/exception reporting.

Sincerely,
David

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for the tag edit...shows you how enamored I was with the exception window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Sincerely, David :)